# Assert with the parameter that contains string

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am using `MSTest` and `Moq` to write unit tests. I want to test that a method is called with the string parameter that contains sub-string.

```
_mockMessageService.Verify(x => x.ShowMessage(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

In above code, I can verify that `ShowMessage` method was called once with some string parameter but I want to make sure that string contain words like `success`, `fail`, `partially success` etc. I can't directly pass entire string because it is not consistent, only part of it is consistent. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are doing unit testing, why is the string message _not_ consistent? Why can't you control the inputs and mocked dependencies so that you can expect a specific message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It.Is<>()` allows for a predicate to be used to verify the parameter

```
_mockMessageService.Verify(x => x.ShowMessage(It.Is<string>(s => 
    s.Containes("success", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || 
    s.Containes("fail", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
    s.Containes("partially success", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
)), Times.Once());
```

Reference: [MOQ Quickstart - Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)